# How do I create and place an input text field from script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

I want to display an input field on the screen from a **script, no editor, no template to work with**. I think I need a `TMP_InputField` but I was unable to position it, see it or interact with it at all.

This is my code so far. I can see the grey background fine and the log has the "InputField created".

```cs
canvas = new GameObject("Canvas");
var c = canvas.AddComponent<Canvas>();
c.renderMode = RenderMode.ScreenSpaceOverlay;

background = new GameObject("Background");
background.transform.parent = canvas.transform;
var img = background.AddComponent<Image>();
img.color = new Color(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.8f);
var rect = img.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
rect.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
rect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(200, 200);

var textField = new GameObject("Input");
textField.transform.parent = canvas.transform;
inputField = textField.AddComponent<TMP_InputField>();
inputField.text = "example";

rect = textField.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
rect.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
rect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(200, 25);

inputField.Select();
inputField.ActivateInputField();

Debug.Log("InputField created");
```

Comment: Have you tried looking it up in the Hierarchy and see where it actually ended up in the scene view?

Comment: Yes. It is in the right place below the canvas.

Comment: Could you add some screenshots of how it looks like in the hierarchy and the scene view when selecting the input field ?

Comment: The path is `Root\Canvas\Input` with position 0, 0. Same for `Root\Canvas\Background` but I can see the background. I don't think its a problem with the hierarchy but with creating the `TMP_InputField`. The few examples I found just did the `AddComponent<TMP_InputField>`, not even the `AddComponent<RectTransform>`.

Comment: In general instead of doing this I would recommend a prefab that is already setup correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting all the required settings for an Input Field. I've managed to initialize it; nevertheless, it's not clickable right now, check the code:

```
    // set it to inputFieldBackground Image
    [SerializeField] private Sprite sprite;

    private void Start()
    {
        var canvas = new GameObject("Canvas");
        var c = canvas.AddComponent<Canvas>();
        c.renderMode = RenderMode.ScreenSpaceOverlay;

        var background = new GameObject("Background");
        background.transform.parent = canvas.transform;
        var img = background.AddComponent<Image>();
        img.color = new Color(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.8f);
        var rect = img.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        rect.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        rect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(200, 200);

        var textField = new GameObject("Input", typeof(CanvasRenderer), typeof(RectTransform), typeof(Image),
            typeof(TMP_InputField));
        textField.transform.parent = canvas.transform;
        textField.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(160, 30);
        textField.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        textField.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text = "example";
        textField.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().targetGraphic = textField.GetComponent<Image>();
        textField.GetComponent<Image>().type = Image.Type.Sliced;
        textField.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = sprite;

        var placeHolder = new GameObject("Placeholder", typeof(CanvasRenderer), typeof(TextMeshProUGUI),
            typeof(LayoutElement));

        var text = new GameObject("Text", typeof(CanvasRenderer), typeof(TextMeshProUGUI));

        var textArea = new GameObject("Text Area", typeof(RectMask2D), typeof(RectTransform));

        textField.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().textViewport = textArea.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        textArea.transform.SetParent(textField.transform);
        textArea.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = Vector3.zero;

        placeHolder.transform.SetParent(textArea.transform);
        text.transform.SetParent(textArea.transform);
        text.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().color = Color.black;
        
        text.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        placeHolder.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = Vector3.zero;


        textField.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().textComponent = text.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();

        rect.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        rect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(200, 25);

        textField.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().Select();
        textField.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().ActivateInputField();

        Debug.Log("InputField created");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like a `textComponent` was missing for me. I added one and now I can see the input field text and can type into it too.